# Artifact в Maven

Tags: java, maven

Что такое artifact в Maven, для чего он нужен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для разработчика Maven библиотеки:
по своей сути Artifact Maven это  [интерфейс](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html) который обязывает разработчика некой библиотеки имплементировать поля описывающие  библиотеку, все это необходимо для однозначной трактовки данной библиотеки в Maven Central.Добавление возможно если библиотека выполняет ряд условий.Это очень вкратце,более полная статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/171493/).

Для пользователя Maven:
Представляет собой некий сторонний или Ваш проект развертываемый в Maven хранилище и подключаемый к любому Вашему проекту.Зависимости Вашего проекта(описанные в файле pom.xml) от сторонних библиотек/плагинов соответственно так же являются артефактами. После объявления новой зависимости ответственность за предоставление актуальной версии проекта/библиотеки/src, отслеживание более сложных (внутренних) зависимостей подключенных проектов/библиотек перекладываеться на плечи Maven.
Синтаксис добавления новой зависимости:

пример добавления **JUnit 4.12**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Не вполне верно. Артефакт - это, в первую очередь, результат сборки maven-проекта. Это может быть и JAR с одними лишь ресурсами, и WAR, и сам по себе pom.xml, и собранный бинарник, и упакованный исходный код. Да, артефакт может выступать в качестве зависимости, но это не является обязательным условием. `<scope>system</scope>` позволяет подключить произвольный внешний JAR.

Comment: @Nofate  Согласен однобоко зациклился на библиотеках.Дополню

Answer (score 1):

Артефакт это общее название для файлов, библиотек, плагинов, исходников.

---

Добавление артефакта необходимо, если вам нужен какой-то функционал этого артефакта на сервере. В туториале от [devcolibri](http://devcolibri.com/4249) приведен пример как поставить на tomcat необходимый фреймворк Spring. Для этого указывают артефакт, который будет запускаться после старта сервера.

---

Источники

- [Apache](http://www.apache-maven.ru/repository.html)
- [Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77382/)

Comment: А что просит указать в настройках tomcat, это для чего надо?

Comment: @JTan, вы про этап как в http://devcolibri.com/4249 на втором шаге?

Comment: да именной этот этап

Comment: @JTan в том пункте указываете какой артефакт нужно будет развернуть при старте сервера

Comment: а для чего это надо, у меня сейчас все работает, мне интересно, для чего и что это, он сам не может создать что ли?